# C# HttpHeaders - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#

I've been getting this error randomly since last few months. I'm not sure what's the exact way to reproduce this, but the code hasn't changed in years, and this issue just happened suddenly..

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.AddHeaderToStore(String name, HeaderStoreItemInfo info)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.CreateAndAddHeaderToStore(String name)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.GetOrCreateHeaderInfo(String name, Boolean parseRawValues)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderValueCollection`1.SetSpecialValue()
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpGeneralHeaders.set_ConnectionClose(Nullable`1 value)
```

All I'm trying to do is to set ConnectionClose to true or null, like this:

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = _closingConnections;
```

But then I'm getting errors about same key already added etc. How can I debug this?

Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible that you are setting this from multiple threads onto the same HttpClient?

Comment: Seems that a worker process intermittently insert duplicate key value into request header dictionary (shown in stack trace). How about checking the existing dictionary keys before assigning the value?

Comment: @Bas Yes, it's from multiple threads

Answer (score 3):

Posting just for the sake of recommending the article because it gave me a clear picture of why it should not be done and how to proceed.

What is key to understand here is that although HttpClient is thread-safe, its DefaultRequestHeaders is not, which is why you're getting this error when multiple threads are trying to set the property. No matter what strategy you attempt to avoid the error, even if you're successful in capturing it, it will not be the most performant approach.

I recommend you read this article called [Using HttpClient as it was intended, because you're not](https://contrivedexample.com/2017/07/01/using-httpclient-as-it-was-intended-because-youre-not/). It provides clear recommendations about how to use HttpClient depending on the different use cases, e.g. if you're always calling the same API, vs if you will be calling different APIs, etc.

In short, you should not be modifying DefaultRequestHeaders from concurrent code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains("ConnectionClose"))
{
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("ConnectionClose");
}
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = _closingConnections
```

Try to clean the value before reassign

Comment: I'm setting _client.DefaultRequestHeaders from multiple threads, will this help?

Answer (score 1):

"DefaultRequestHeaders" property is not thread safe. If you are making multi-threaded call to setup Http header for HttpClient you may encounter this issue.

There is an open bug for this - https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1500

As its HTTPHandler that manages port; try sharing "HttpHandler" with between threads and making a new HttpClient per thread. That should solve this issue.

Sample code -

```
class Program
{

    private static HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();


    private static HttpClient GetHTTPClient()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
        return client;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tasks = new[]
       {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MakeCalls()),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MakeCalls()),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MakeCalls())
        };
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }

    static void MakeCalls()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.mySiteUrl.com/api/Employee/1");
        var client = GetHTTPClient();
        var httpResponse = client.GetAsync(uri);
        //Do something with httpResponse
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to your problem is to encapsulate the addition of headers using the lock (obj) statement, this will make the thread that wants to continue with your code have to wait for the completion of what is inside that block

```
class Program
{

    private static readonly object Locker = new object();
    private static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    static async Task Main()
    {
        var MultipleTasks = new[]
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => await YourMethod()),
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => await YourMethod()),
        };

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }

    static async Task YourMethod()
    {
        lock (Locker) 
        {
            // Here you add the headers you want, by the way, you must not add more than 1 time a header with the same key or it will throw an exception
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", "value");
        }
          
        var Response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://...");

        // Here you do what you want with the HttpResponseMessage
    }
}
```